# SOLR 6 - indexing documents

Tags: indexing, solr, document

I need to index documents on a SOLR server and update a specific field. I am using post jar on Windows for indexing the documents.

First question: is it possible to set the value of the required field directly from the post tool?

If not, *text* field is not stored but just indexed. As such, when I am doing the update of the field, the *text* field is losing all the content. I am updating the field using the http update (POST). The post parameters are: {"id":"D:\TESTNEWATTACH\AnexaNr.docx","PCC_TABLENAME":{"set":"PCC_CRM_ATTACH"}}

The main question is: how can I index a document and set a field belonging to that document without losing the document content search ability?

Answer (score 0):

To update just a single field in a document, all fields has to be set as stored. If you don't have the fields set as stored, you'll lose the content when doing the update (as the process internally is retrieve document, update document, resubmit document).

The `post` tool supports giving arbitrary parameters to the update handler:

> -params "=[&=...]" (values must be URL-encoded; these pass through to Solr update request)

.. which you can use with `literal.fieldname=value` to [provide a value for the field(s) directly in the post request](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Solr+Cell+using+Apache+Tika#UploadingDatawithSolrCellusingApacheTika-InputParameters).

> literal.<fieldname>
>
> Populates a field with the name supplied with the specified value for each document. The data can be multivalued if the field is multivalued.

Comment: Thanks very much. I tried with -params but I was not able to do it. I receive an error.

Comment: I tried something like: D:\Solr\solr_6\bin>java -jar -Dauto=true -Dc=gettingstarted -params "literal.PCC_TABLENAME=PCC_CRM_ATTACH" -Ddata=files "D:\Solr\solr_6\example\exampledocs\post.jar" "d:\TestNewAttach\AnexaNr.docx"

Comment: One new approach that I have in mind is to create a stored field and use a copyfield directive to copy the content to the _text_ field into my new field. But if I would be able to use post for adding a field value to my document would be much better. Can you please provide me an example for the params tag?